# What is the best way to learn TeX?

Tags: tex-core, programming, learning

As opposed to LaTeX, which is addressed in another question.

Most of the references I've seen get too complex too quickly. I'm looking for something that gives me a top-down view of the language - what the parts of a document are and how (and when) each is processed before proceeding to infinite detail like character classes (e.g.). Something heavily example-based, with real-world examples, would be helpful as well. I just find the language incredibly obscure and difficult to grok.

Comment: I wonder if this is really possible. At a TeX level the 'parts of a document' are really not that relevant. TeX typesets 'stuff', and although you can alter how the stuff looks, TeX doesn't really care about structure. That is what LaTeX adds to TeX, by introducing a programming layer which does know about document structure.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The TeXBook (by [Knuth himself](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html)) is actually great! It starts with examples and explains clearly all the things starting from the simplest things that you're most likely to need, and goes sufficiently deep. It is a strange book in that it needs to be read in multiple passes, but you can do it. It's worth reading, especially since it also gives you insights that can be later crucial — into typography, why Knuth made the choices he made, and other issues about the internals of TeX.

Comment: The TeXBook is kinda strange. One chapter he will explain something and the next he will say "ignore what I mentioned previously, this is the truth".

Comment: +1, my recommendation, with a copy of TeX by Topic by your side. *needs to be read in multiple passes* - I didn't find this, except for the infamous Appendix D.

Comment: @dreamlax: He's very up front that some of the things he says are white lies. The point is not that what he said previously was wrong, merely that he omitted certain things that were not important right away.

Comment: @dreamlax: that happens *all the time* in various courses of learning

Comment: BTW today I would recommend not *The TeXbook* as a first read, but the truly excellent *A Beginner's Book of TeX* by Seroul and Levy. It comes highly recommended by Hans Hagen in the preface to the ConTeXt manual as “the book that turns every beginner into an expert”, “For newcomers we advise (3)” and “Again, we would advise (3)”, and he's right. Not only does it give you a very good mental model of how TeX works and how to bend it to your will, but more than that, it will make you fall in love with TeX as a program. (I don't want to edit my answer 8.5 years later as that might be misleading.)

Comment: Anyone actually looking for quick reference or even attempting to understand things in TeX should avoid this book, it has bad structure, zero definition of syntax of commands, poor to non-existent of explanation of what basic commands do and all the existing explanation were probably translated from English to Chinese to Russian to Sumer and back to English and printed plus half of the things you have to figure out on your own in exercises, it is simply useless unless one's life is just TeX...

Comment: @leosenko I'll agree with the first part: *The TeXbook* is not structured as a quick reference. (Everything is in there, but you have to know where to look.) Like any textbook on any topic, you are expected to read and understand it; exercises are a great way to engage you in active learning. (But today's users probably expect to start using a program without spending a few days learning, instead spreading out that learning "on demand".) It's also less useful if you're using TeX in ways it was not designed for, e.g. if you're using LaTeX. Apart from that, syntax, explanation, etc are fine IMO.

Answer (score 21):

Roger, you may have noticed something about the replies to your question. There is no consensus. This indicates that there is no real standard path to learning TeX. I've learned TeX the same way most of these folk have. I've read The TeXbook. I've read 'TeX by Topic'. I've spend hours, days, years pouring over OPC (other people's code) as the spittle drips from my mouth onto the page and my brain freezes and causes global body-locking until I fall off my chair in a dead faint.  I've screamed and yelled at the impersonal sky-gods who have decreed that the people who know TeX will never set up easy and accessible methods of teaching and learning TeX except by the hard and stony path that they have trod. There shall be no web-sites where tex code can be looked at and reviewed by the tex-sages. There shall be no books on advanced TeX programming or methods of learning the TeX way implements standard algorithms or do standard thing that are in chapter 1 of most programming books. There shall be no path but the one; the path of figuring it all out by yourself.

You see, Roger, the *TeX community is not like other communities of software enthusiasts. In other communities there are books, magazines, classes, websites, and endless ways to learn the tips and tricks of programming in their language. People who know things are glad to help you, even if you are asking things that require them to read more than 10 lines of your code. Sometimes lots of code. There are places to get code reviews of your code. They actually like to spread their knowledge and watch their language spread around the world, creating thriving and pulsing groups of enthusiastic coders.

But in the *TeX world, we hate sharing what we know. Especially with those who don't know and want to learn.  We're definitely not going to make it easy for you. If you weren't lazy, you'd do what we did, read the TeXbook, read 'TeX by Topic', read OTP, drool on our desks till you faint. You know, what non-lazy people who don't want others to do all their work for them do.

Let's see. It's almost 2011. TeX was created in 1979 and 'finalized' in 1982. That's almost 30 years ago. Ruby was released in 1995, 15 years ago. Last time I was in Borders, there was a whole shelf or two of Ruby programming books. There were none on programming TeX.

You know what happens when there is no simple path to learning something? Knowledge is lost over time. Are there more people willing to tread the hard and stony path to learning TeX today than 10 years ago, or less? Where is *TeX, and by extension, typographically beautiful documents, going to be in 50 years? Will *TeX, or any descendants, exist?

Comment: I'm not sure the comparison with Ruby is entirely fair. TeX is a rather specialised language, whereas Ruby ismuch more general and so do attract more _programmers_. (For Ruby one could substitute a number of other languages, of course.) I've also found that there is support available in terms of 'this is how you can'. Some of the posts to c.t.t. include _lots_ of very clever ideas. It's just that in the main there is an expectation that to understand what happens you'll run the clever stuff with `\tracingall`! I guess that writing a better book that _The TeXBook_ is actually very hard!

Comment: Why do you think he would drool on *your* desk, bev?

Comment: @SamB - actually, looking at it now, I'm quite embarrassed at how many typos are in there. I might fix them, or I might leave them as a living monument to how careless I am and how carefully I need to edit.

Comment: I love this answer. It's exactly the way I feel when I go to Google for an answer to some seemingly simple TeX question and get either nothing or 100 copies of the same web page from some university.

Comment: "we hate sharing what we know" Ahem. You realize that TeX by Topic & TeX for the Impatient have been open source for the last 20 years? Also, I learned tons from comp.text.tex, and these days tex.stackexchange is quite valuable. The TeX programming community is just not as large as other languages, but I think there is nothing wrong with its helpfulness.

Answer (score 17):

Victor Eijkhout's [Tex by Topic](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html) provides for a good reference. It can complement more tutorial-style texts.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this reference a few times - but it turns out you are right, it's just a reference, not a tutorial.

Comment: "just a reference". There is a ton of illustrative examples in it. Parse them slowly and carefully.

Answer (score 8):

I learned from [A Gentle Introduction to TeX](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/gentle/gentle.pdf) (PDF file). I also have a copy of Knuth's *TeXbook* which I look at once in a while.

Comment: this manual is also in tex live, so can be accessed by typing `texdoc gentle` at a command prompt.

Answer (score 8):

Also see Making TeX Work and TeX For The Impatient. Obligatory FAQ link:
https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ol-books

Answer (score 8):

TeX has several components, including (1) typesetting (2) fonts and (3) macros.

Often, it is macros that people have the most difficulty with.  For this there are some key concepts, such as the token stream and the action of the expansion of macros.

The expansion of a macro edits the stream of tokens.  This is a key concept.  Try running some very simple macros with `\tracingall` on.

A good lesson would be to read through and understand the output of

```
 $ tex '\relax \tracingall \input story \end'
```

Answer (score 5):

As for a different method,

I learned by building LaTeX documents and then looking at the TeX generated.  This is so I could associate LaTeX commands with their TeX structures.

Much different from learning from a book.

Comment: How do you look at the TeX generated?

Comment: `\tracingmacros` (IIRC) does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

"Most of the references I've seen get too complex too quickly." I tried very hard not to do this in [Formatting Information](http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/), so I'd appreciate any feedback. Since TUG published it, I have been busy with other things, so it needs an update, but the essentials are all still valid.

Comment: Hello, your book is great! It is recommended by several people at [this other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex). This question is about plain TeX only, though.

Answer (score 0):

Although I must admit I haven't read it, the obvious choice would be to go straight to the source with Knuth: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html

Answer (score 0):

The TEXBOOK is necessary to read for beginner.  When you use TEX, you will meet many many problems.  You Google them, and you solve them.