# Cannot use \textit or \url in \edef

Tags: macros, errors

I'm trying to write a Tex command that automatically prints out attribution information for images I use in my document. I created 2 different commands. The first one is `\nounattr` (with 3 parameters) which takes the image's name, the author and the link of the image. The second command is `\printnounattrs` which has no arguments, but should simply print a list of all attributions added before using `\nounattr`. I was able to implement these commands and get a simple list, but I cannot add any styling to the list whatsoever.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{nounattr}[2018/01/03 The noun project attribution]

\RequirePackage{svg}
\RequirePackage{url}

\newcommand\printnounattrs{}
\newcommand\nounattr[3]{\edef\printnounattrs{\printnounattrs#1 pictogram werd ontworpen door #2 van The Noun Project, onder de Creative Commons license (CC BY 3.0). Zie #3. }}
```

An MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{nounattr}
\begin{document}
    \nounattr{Protein}{Ben Markoch}{https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=protein\&i=54837}
    \nounattr{Peptides}{Fredrik Edfors}{https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=peptide\&i=66903}

    \printnounattrs
\end{document}
```

Which yields:
[image]

I would however like to add some styling into the edef in order for `#1 pictogram` to be printed italic and that the url is propely defined as a url using `\url{#3}`. I changed `\nounattr` to be:

```
\newcommand\nounattr[3]{\edef\printnounattrs{\printnounattrs\textit{#1 pictogram} werd ontworpen door #2 van The Noun Project, onder de Creative Commons license (CC BY 3.0). Zie \url{#3}. }}
```

But this gives me a `undefined control sequence` error. I don't understand what's happening and how I can possibly fix this?

Comment: Indeed some commands like `\textit` are *not expandable*, which means that they can't be used in an `\edef` context. There are many questions about this concept on this site, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35039/35864 and linked questions.

Comment: You may want to look into 'list' implementations from `etoolbox` or `expl3` instead. I think they can usually deal with these things as they don't go full `\edef` on the contents.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your help so far. I can't use `\def` as it causes TeX to go out of memory for some reason. I will take a look at the list implementations you mentioned :)

Comment: Yes, I realised that after I had a closer look at what the code was doing. I have removed the `\def` suggestion from my comment.

Comment: Here's one that should work: `\expandafter\def\expandafter\printnounattrs\expandafter{\printnounattrs` instead of `\edef\printnounattrs{\printnounattrs`

Comment: @moeve Can you convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @PieterVerschaffelt BTW, a suggestion:  `\ccby` of package `ccicons`.

Comment: @Fran thanks! I can defenitely use this in my attributions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a large group of TeX macros/commands that can't be used (as expected) in an `\edef` context. Those macros are called *not expandable*. This aspect of TeX programming is one that creeps up on one sooner or later and is well worth reading up on if one intends to go a bit further in (La)TeX coding. There are a great many questions about issues like this on this site (for example [What are the differences between \def, \edef, \gdef and \xdef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353138/35864), [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451/35864), ...), but I don't know about a good systematic introduction except for the typical TeX references such as the TeX book or TeX by Topic (see for example [What is the best way to learn TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53/35864), [Should I read Donald Knuth's The TeXbook?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10841/35864)).

In your particular case `\textit` and `\url` are not expandable and will thus break when used in `\edef`.

If you want to retain the structure of your current approach you can replace the `\edef` with `\expandafter`s and a `\def`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\RequirePackage{url}

\newcommand\printnounattrs{}
\newcommand\nounattr[3]{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\printnounattrs\expandafter{%
    \printnounattrs
    \textit{#1 pictogram} werd ontworpen door #2 van The Noun Project,
    onder de Creative Commons license (CC BY 3.0).
    Zie \url{#3}. }%
}
\begin{document}
    \nounattr{Protein}{Ben Markoch}{https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=protein&i=54837}
    \nounattr{Peptides}{Fredrik Edfors}{https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=peptide&i=66903}
    \nounattr{Peptides}{Schmeptides}{https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=peptide&i=123&pq=v_w20w}

    \printnounattrs
\end{document}
```

While the `\edef` would try to expand everything in its argument as far as possible, the `\expandafter\def\expandafter\printnounattrs\expandafter{\printnounattrs` expands only the `\printnounattrs` in the definition exactly once, which means that we can concatenate our list as expected. (The simple `\def\printnounattrs{\printnounattrs...}` would lead to an infinite loop because that would to define the macro `\printnounattrs` to expand to `\printnounattrs`.)

Note that with this approach `\url` suffers from its usual issues that the URL can't contain `%`, `#`, `^^` or end with `\` since it is used as an argument to a command.

---

If I were to write a macro for a similar task from scratch I would probably look into using the powerful list macros of `etoolbox` or LaTeX3/`expl3`.

Here is a naive implementation with `etoolbox`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand\mylist{}
\newcommand\nounattr[3]{%
  \listadd{\mylist}{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}

\newcommand*{\printnounattr}[3]{%
  \textit{#1 pictogram} werd ontworpen door #2 van The Noun Project,
  onder de Creative Commons license (CC BY 3.0).
  Zie \url{#3}.
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\printnounattr@i}[1]{%
  \printnounattr#1}
\newcommand*{\printnounattrs}{%
  \forlistloop{\printnounattr@i}{\mylist}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \nounattr{Protein}{Ben Markoch}{https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=protein&i=54837}
    \nounattr{Peptides}{Fredrik Edfors}{https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=peptide&i=66903}
    \nounattr{Peptides}{Schmeptides}{https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=peptide&i=123&pq=v_w20w}

    \printnounattrs
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`\edef` expands all commands to the fullest. However not all commands can be expanded, like e.g. `\textit` because it doesn't know what to do with the text when it's not in "printing mode". If you still however want to expand other tokens while leaving e.g. `\textit` untouched it you could use `\noexpand` (or `\unexpanded` if multple tokens) to prevent it from expanding (whilst all the others are):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\a{alpha}
\edef\b{\noexpand\textit{\a}}
\show\b
\begin{document}
\b
\end{document}
```

Shows this in the log:

```
> \b=macro:
->\textit {alpha}.
l.4 \show\b
```

You can read more about `\noexpand` (and the related `\unexpanded`) at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519/85834)