# Learning Latex in a holistic way?

Tags: learning, tutorials

I would like to get your opinion on the broad subject of learning `LaTeX`. At first, I started with the online-editor, then I installed required software on my laptop. I learned as I went, seeking and mimicking good typesetting examples, finding solutions to the problems as they appear. I have done typesetting for a number of documents and created several books for myself. However, I am still somewhat dissatisfied with my own knowledge, as it seems that it is not as systemic, as I would like it to be. Hence, I would like to seek advice in this regard. In your opinion, (a) what is the best strategy to progress from the novice to the “power user” and (b) what are those `LaTeX` packages (in your opinion) that every “power user” should be familiar with?
Your thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: "User(s)": an infinite set. The question is open-ended. Latex can typeset anything. (1) Pick a skill area (fonts, layout, floats, lists, vertical scripts, colors, bibliographic programming with biblatex, indexing, etc). (2) Pick a subject area (quantum optics, syntactic trees, logic, translations, Garamond, hieroglyphs (a good area at the moment is Mayan)). (3) Combine (1) and (2). (4) Reiterate with another skill and another subject. (5) The packages follow the use. Based on questions, making math mode dynamically parametric would be *extremely* useful.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a package, font, tool, book or other off-site resource** are off-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it or, if applicable, ask on [Software Recommendations SX](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As your learning system has been the examples, a more systematic method (but not necessarily more effective) can be only read some boring books from beginning to end, as well as manuals of the packages. Remember, `texdoc` is your friend. Said that, remember that you will *never* be an expert in everything, so  the first question is what *you* still need for *your* documents.

Comment: I think Knuth's `The TeXbook` would be the place to start: [Should I read Donald Knuth's The TeXbook?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10841/4301).

Comment: **Secret of the LaTeX Illuminatti**: Find the source code (source2e) and learn how to read it.

Comment: This question has many duplicates (many questions on the site on how to go about learning LaTeX); the one I remember (because I wrote an answer) is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385649/a-latex-course-for-intermediate-users-stuck-on-the-learning-curve), but there are many others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)

Answer (score 2):

I found this tutorial very helpful:

http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/rhigginbottom/latex/lectures.html

It's from 2012, but is still very useful.
It has a section on pstricks, though you may prefer PGF Tikz which is not in this tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

There are many websites and manuals, but I think the most useful manual is here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/LaTeX.pdf