# Is there a valid source to read about the description and examples of an arbitrary TEX command such as \ifnum?

Tags: conditionals

When I encounter a new TEX command to learn for the first time such as \ifnum, I do not know where to start to read about the description and examples. I know ctan.org is full of TEX packages but is not easily searchable. Is there a valid source to read about the description and examples of an arbitrary TEX command such as \ifnum?

Comment: Valid source means a source written by the people who design the commands. Or a source approved by the TEX commands designers.

Comment: texfaq.org is usually a good place to start and the list of contributors is impressive: http://www.texfaq.org/authors

Comment: My browder said it is not secure: texfac

Comment: For the TeX core many people would probably point to Knuth's TeXBook, whose source is available on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbook) (note that you may not compile that source). That's as official as it gets. Another well-liked and often-cited source of TeX core commands is [TeX by Topic](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic). But those only cover the stuff that is part of the TeX core. If you want to know more about LaTeX core commands you need other sources and if you want to know about commands from packages, you need to consult the package documentation.

Comment: Possibly interesting https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10841/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668/35864.

Comment: Thanks, without compiling how to get Kunuth's book?

Comment: You'd have to buy a (used) copy or go to your local library, I'm afraid. I am not aware of a free *and* legal version of the TeXbook on the web.

Comment: Thanks, compiling does not work?

Comment: If you are just interested in a commands reference then [TeX by Topic](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic), [TeX for the Impatient](https://ctan.org/pkg/impatient) or [TeX-nutshell](https://ctan.org/pkg/tex-nutshell) are probably no worse than the TeXbook.

Comment: No, the source of the TeXbook available on CTAN has some guards preventing it from being compiled and the license does not allow you to compile it (`All rights are reserved! The file is distributed only for people to see its examples of TeX input, not for use in the preparation of books like The TeXbook. Permission for any other use of this file must be obtained in writing from the copyright holder and also from the publisher (Addison-Wesley).`). I expect that it is not impossible to circumvent these guards, but I doubt many people will be happy to assist in that endeavour.

Comment: @moewe Thank you so much for your detailed very useful answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “official” source for TeX primitive commands is the TeXbook, whose TeX source is available online (even on CTAN), but not for making the printed copy.

The source starts with

```
% This manual is copyright (C) 1984 by the American Mathematical Society.
% All rights are reserved!
% The file is distributed only for people to see its examples of TeX input,
% not for use in the preparation of books like The TeXbook.
% Permission for any other use of this file must be obtained in writing
% from the copyright holder and also from the publisher (Addison-Wesley).
```

which means that the file should not even be used for *reading* the book. Of course, it is allowed to *quote* small parts of it for the purpose of documentation or description, by citing the source. For longer parts, permission from the publisher has to be obtained.

Here's the description of `\ifnum` (The TeXbook, page 209)

> • `\ifnum`⟨number<sub>1</sub>⟩⟨relation⟩⟨number<sub>2</sub>⟩ (compare two integers)
>
> The ⟨relation⟩ must be either ‘`<`<sub>12</sub>’ or ‘`=`<sub>12</sub>’ or ’`>`<sub>12</sub>’.
> The two integer numbers are compared to each other in the usual way, and
> the result is true or false accordingly.

You can instead consult “TeX by Topic”, by Victor Eijkhout, which is freely available on CTAN and included in full versions of TeX Live (`texdoc texbytopic`). On page 85 you read

[image]

The book has also several examples of usage and covers *all* the TeX primitives.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer!