# New line and paragraph in TeX

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, plain-tex

I have been a writing a simple program using TeX programming like

```
Hello, World!
How are you.
\bye
```

I want the two sentences to in different lines but they come in same line. Using `\\` it gives an error undefined control sequence. How can it be shifted to new line and also how to start a new paragraph?

Comment: I am asking about TeX and not LaTeX, I know using \\ will shift me to the next line in LaTeX and how this would be done in TeX?

Comment: By different lines you're probably referring to `\par` (after `Hello, World!`).

Comment: Yes, done for that :) How to shift new paragraph?

Comment: Can you tell me where can I find a simple guide for TeX programming ?

Comment: @luneart - the query is about creating simple documents using Plain TeX, not LaTeX.

Comment: The duplicate should be http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53/15925

Answer (score 7):

The basic structural element of a typeset document is the paragraph. TeX separates paragraphs by `\par` command which is automatically inserted at each empty line in source document (when the common catcode settings are done). Thus, you can try two approaches:

- separate paragraphs by empty lines
- read some basics introduction to TeX, for example [M. Doob: A gentle introduction to TeX](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/info/gentle/gentle.pdf) or (if you understand Czech:) [Olšák: TeX pro pragmatiky](http://petr.olsak.net/tpp.html)

Answer (score 6):

Use `\par` to start a new paragraph (or leave a blank line between text blocks):

```
Hello, World!

How are you.
\bye
```

or

```
Hello, World!\par
How are you.
\bye
```

Alternatively, but highly unlikely, use `\obeylines`:

```
\obeylines
Hello, World!
How are you.
\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to consult the introduction on Latex, see this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner) or directly [The (not so) short introduction to LaTeX2e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf).

The particular answer to your question is to use `\\` or `\newline`.

Comment: IMHO, OP needs the introduction to TeX, no to LaTeX.

Comment: @wipet After all, OP is specifically asking about Plain :)

Comment: well, my answer was made before the edits :)

Comment: @luneart The MWE in version one is clearly for plain!