# Where can I read about the TeX commands not LaTeX commands // Math commands

Tags: plain-tex

Which online resources are good to learn how to type in TeX rather than LaTeX ? 
I am confused as to where to post this question given that most if not all code here is for LaTeX specific questions.

I want to know all the basic math commands for TeX rather than LaTeX; 
Sectioning and documentation commands etc ....

Thank you

Comment: See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-tex/74#74

Comment: It's a simplification but the idea behind LaTeX is it provides you with a whole load of TeX macros, that is, it gives you a handy, user-friendly, intuitive construct like `\section{}` which is ultimately defined in TeX, in a way that TeX can understand. I may be butchering this a bit, but basically the thing about TeX is you either have to build the sectioning commands yourself from scratch, or go and find some that someone else has done, the first port of call being LaTeX

Comment: I think the tag you're looking for is `plain-TeX`, *not* `tex-core`.

Comment: Obvious place to start with plain is _The TeXbook_ ...

Comment: @JosephWright -- but the texbook isn't free on line.  a tutorial that is, is michael doob's *a gentle introduction to tex*.  it's in tex live, so can be viewed by typing `texdoc gentle` at a command line prompt.  that's also cited in the question linked by @CarLaTeX.

Comment: duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53/579